# Input file into array, unique word

Tags: c++, arrays, input, ifstream

I am working on creating a program that will read a file of lyrics, songs, and artists. There are approximately 100 artists, 100 songs, and about 10,000 unique lyrics. I know how to bring the lyrics into an array; however I am having trouble qualifying them as unique. I haven't had much experience with c++ and everything I've seen online for arrays and ifstream doesn't mention much about qualifying the data going into an array. I am not looking for code verbatim, simply looking for a couple hints or tips as to what I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by qualifying them as unique? That you don't want to store the same lyrics twice in the array?

Comment: Correct, I only want each word to appear once in the array, and I want to to report the element location upon adding.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to use the `std::map` class. Something like this...

```
map<string, int> words;
string word;
while (ifstream >> word)
    ++words[word];
```

At this point, you can go through `words` and find the entries with have a value of `1`, since they were only added once (unique)

Comment: Cool thanks for the quick reply! I'll play around with it and see if I can get that to work. Thanks!